# Is there any difference between the two codes?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I am currently still relatively new to Tensorflow. I am having some trouble with these two pieces of code.

Code A:

```
self.h1_layer = tf.layers.dense(self.x, self.n_nodes_hl1, activation=tf.nn.relu, name="h1")
self.h2_layer = tf.layers.dense(self.h1_layer, self.n_nodes_hl2, activation=tf.nn.relu, name="h2")
self.h3_layer = tf.layers.dense(self.h2_layer, self.n_nodes_hl3, activation=tf.nn.relu, name="h3")

self.logits = tf.layers.dense(self.h3_layer, self.num_of_classes, name="output")
```

Code B:

```
self.hidden_1_layer = {
    'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.num_of_words, self.h1])),
    'biases' : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.h1]))
}

self.hidden_2_layer = {
    'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.h1, self.h2])),
    'biases' : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.h2]))
}

self.hidden_3_layer = {
    'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.h2, self.h3])),
    'biases' : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.h3]))
}

self.final_output_layer = {
    'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.h3, self.num_of_classes])),
    'biases' : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.num_of_classes]))
}

layer1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, self.hidden_1_layer['weights']), self.hidden_1_layer['biases'])
layer1 = tf.nn.relu(layer1)

layer2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer1, self.hidden_2_layer['weights']), self.hidden_2_layer['biases'])
layer2 = tf.nn.relu(layer2)

layer3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer2, self.hidden_3_layer['weights']), self.hidden_3_layer['biases'])
layer3 = tf.nn.relu(layer3)

output = tf.matmul(layer3, self.final_output_layer['weights']) + self.final_output_layer['biases']
```

Are they the same thing? Can both Codes A & B weights and biases be saved with tf.train.Saver() ?

Thanks

Edit: 
I am facing issues using Code A to generate prediction. It seems that logits of Code A is always changing.

The full code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os

from utils import Utils as utils

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'

class Neural_Network:
    # Neural Network Setup
    num_of_epoch = 50

    n_nodes_hl1 = 500
    n_nodes_hl2 = 500
    n_nodes_hl3 = 500

    def __init__(self):
        self.num_of_classes = utils.get_num_of_classes()
        self.num_of_words = utils.get_num_of_words()

        # placeholders
        self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.num_of_words])
        self.y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, self.num_of_classes])

        with tf.name_scope("model"):
            self.h1_layer = tf.layers.dense(self.x, self.n_nodes_hl1, activation=tf.nn.relu, name="h1")
            self.h2_layer = tf.layers.dense(self.h1_layer, self.n_nodes_hl2, activation=tf.nn.relu, name="h2")
            self.h3_layer = tf.layers.dense(self.h2_layer, self.n_nodes_hl3, activation=tf.nn.relu, name="h3")

            self.logits = tf.layers.dense(self.h3_layer, self.num_of_classes, name="output")

    def predict(self):
        return self.logits

    def make_prediction(self, query):
        result = None

        with tf.Session() as sess:
            sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

            saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('saved_models/testing.meta')
            saver.restore(sess, 'saved_models/testing')

            # for variable in tf.trainable_variables():
            #     print sess.run(variable)

            prediction = self.predict()
            pre, prediction = sess.run([self.logits, prediction], feed_dict={self.x : query})
            print pre
            prediction = prediction.tolist()
            prediction = tf.nn.softmax(prediction)
            prediction = sess.run(prediction)
            print prediction

            return utils.get_label_from_encoding(prediction[0])

    def train(self, data):
        prediction = self.predict()

        cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=self.y))
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

        with tf.Session() as sess:
            sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

            writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("mygraph/logs", tf.get_default_graph())

            for epoch in range(self.num_of_epoch):
                optimised, loss = sess.run([optimizer, cost],
                                           feed_dict={self.x: data['values'], self.y: data['labels']})

                if epoch % 1 == 0:
                    print("Completed Training Cycle: " + str(epoch) + " out of " + str(self.num_of_epoch))
                    print("Current Loss: " + str(loss))

                    saver = tf.train.Saver()
                    saver.save(sess, 'saved_models/testing')
                    print("Model saved")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR**: The operations are essentially the same but the *variables creation* and *initialization* methods are different.

If you trace the code from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/python/layers/core.py), you will eventually get to a stage where the code is calling `tf.get_variable` to initialize variables. In your example above, since `kernel_initializer` and `bias_initializer` is not set, they will default to `None` and `tf.zeros_initializer()` respectively ([see Dense API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dense)). When `None` is passed to `tf.get_variable` as an initializer, a `glorot_uniform_initializer` will be used:

> If initializer is None (the default), the default initializer passed
>   in the variable scope will be used. If that one is None too, a
>   glorot_uniform_initializer will be used. The initializer can also be a
>   Tensor, in which case the variable is initialized to this value and
>   shape.

More on tf.get_variable can be found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_variable).

For one case, you used a `tf.random_normal` initializer for both kernel weights and bias weights, but for the other, you used `tf.layers.dense` and will result in a `glorot_uniform_initializer` for kernel weights and `zeros_initializer` for bias weights as no parameters were passed to `tf.layers.dense`.

To your second question on whether they can be saved, yes they can.

As a last note, you have to be careful when using `tf.Variable` as it might complicate things when the scopes are not properly set.

Comment: I am facing some issues using my model A for prediction. Particularly after passing in the same input for n times, the n logits will always be different. However, I do not have such problems with model B. Is the reason due to what you have explained above?

Comment: If you're saving and restoring the weights and doing everything else correctly, this shouldn't happen. Adding more code to the above question or asking another question would help in understanding the problem.

Comment: I have added more code. Is there any mistakes in my implementation?

Comment: I'm not sure how you're feeding in the inputs. Are they always the same? Look at [`tf.set_random_seed`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/set_random_seed) and try and make everything deterministic.

Comment: Inputs are fed in by converting text into a vector (Bag of Words) method. I keyed in the same word each time. Does this help?

Comment: P.S. I posted an edit previously but it was wrong. It's really hard to debug this without your code and data to try and dig deeper.

Comment: Hi, after trying with a simpler example (checking if a number is even or odd), I found out something. It appears that if i use `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())` after restoring my model, then the logit value change. Is the error due to this? Should i initialize variables after restoring?

Comment: Running that after restoring your model overwrites all restored values.

Comment: So if I run it before restoring my model then it wont overwrite the restored values? Because sometimes I do get a using unintialized value error.

Comment: See section on restoring variables [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables).